# translate drupal commerce product titles in views

Tags: views, commerce, i18n-l10n

I have enabled the necessary i18n and l10n modules and I have been able to translate content without any trouble. I am now trying to translate some drupal commerce products. Using the title module I replaced the title of the product with a title field.

The product translations are showing correctly on the product display and cart pages but I also created a view with some products. For some reason the product title doesn't get translated in the view. The add to cart button does get translated however.

How can I get my products to show the correctly translated title in my view like they do on the product display page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution. I rewrote the results of the `Commerce Product: Title` Field and used the replacement pattern `[title_field]`. The translation then showed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You are not the only one dealing with this complete trans did not happen in D7. Try this contrib module, [Title](https://www.drupal.org/project/title).

> While working on the new content translation system for Drupal 7, we
>   (the Drupal core i18n team) faced the need to convert node titles to
>   the Field API in order to make nodes fully translatable.
>
> We were not able to make this happen in Drupal 7 core ... so we
>   decided to find a solution for this in contrib: the idea is replacing
>   node titles with fields à la Automatic Nodetitles.
>
> This will be exploited by the related Entity Translation project.

Comment: Thanks for your response but in my question I already stated that I am using the Title module